# Adding unlocked rows into protected Excel sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an Excel sheet where I show previous records to people and make them add new records using 'add row' functionality.

So I am making my excel sheet protected so they can not tamper with older records. And I am keeping one row unlocked where they can start adding new information.
I also checked the 'Allow adding new rows' option in protection dialog box.

The problem is when I add a new row in the protected sheet, all the cells in that row are locked and I am unable to make an input through it.

Is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add row just below unlocked row to avoid the issue.

[image]
**Using VBA**

You can explicitly specify the `locked=false` for new rows.
Try below sample code.

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "test"
    Rows(5).Insert
    Rows(5).Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, but what if I want to add the row manually by clicking insert new row?

Comment: @mihsathe Check out the image. I hope it makes thing more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The easy workaround without using macros is as follows:

1. You need two unprotected rows
2. Hide the first one
3. Protect the sheet and allow insertion/deletion of rows (not formatting.. they could unhide the row)

People then can add rows via HOME -> Insert -> Insert Sheet Rows or delete them in the same way.
(people can't select the whole rows because of possible locked cells on the right and press [CTRL]+[+])

DONE!